# Obter dados de outro Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Não estou conseguindo obter um telefone relacionado a um usuário na *View* `edit()`. Consigo obter o número do telefone no `ver()` mas não no `edit()`.

Controller **Patient**:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Patient->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid patient'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Patient->saveall($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The patient has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => '../patients/index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The patient could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $phone = $this->Phone->find('all');
        $this->set(array('phone' => $phone));
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Patient.' . $this->Patient->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Patient->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($phone as $phones): ?>  

<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('phone_number',array('label'=>'Telefone','value'=>$phones['Phone']['phone_number']),array('class'=>'form-control'));
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Model **Patient**:

```
public $hasMany = array('Phones'=> array('dependent' => true)) ;
}
```

Model **Phone**:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Patient');
}
```

Quando eu tento acessar a página dá o seguinte erro:

> Error: Call to a member function find() on null File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cifisio\app\Controller\PatientsController.php Line: 87
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diretamente de um `Controller`, você só tem acesso ao seu `Model` correspondente. Para obter acesso ao `Model` relacionado, que no caso é o *Phone*, você precisa fazer assim:

```
$phone = $this->Patient->Phone->find('all');
```

É sobre isso que o erro *"Call to a member function find() on null"* se refere.

Comment: Bom ele listou agora, mas quando eu modifico o telefone ele não atualiza no banco de dados.

Comment: Isso já é outra questão: o método para salvar é [`saveAll()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array), com o **A** maiúsculo. O PHP é *case-sensitive*.